# Delay is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, blink

Why this is not working

```
$('#upload-title').css({ background: '#ffffff' }).delay(800).css({ background: '#00FF72' });
```

I want that my #upload-title. Is white for 0.5 sec. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a timeout, delay is meant for use with animations:

```
$('#upload-title').css({
    background : '#eeeeff'
});
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#upload-title').css({
        background : '#00FF72'
    });
}, 800);
```

Comment: I personaly prefer Guffa's, chained approach.

Comment: You don't *need* to use a timeout.

Comment: I do like the queue method more, didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 8):

The `delay` method delays things in the effects queue, and `css` is not an effects method.

You can add the `css` call to the queue using the `queue` method:

```
$('#upload-title').css({ background: '#ffffff' }).delay(500).queue(function(){
  $(this).css({ background: '#00FF72' });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/BxJ3Z/

Comment: Works great! -- 
`$('newPost').css("background-color", "#D6F5D6").fadeIn('slow').delay(1500).queue(function () {
$(this).css("background-color", "#F1F1F1");
$(this).removeClass('newCommentItem');
});`

Answer (score 1):

`.delay()` works with animations, use jquery .`animate()` instead http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Animate doesn't work with colors. You need a plugin for that.

Comment: good point indeed, although jquery ui extends the animate function to include colours.

Comment: only looking at about 4k (gzipped) to add in all the neat jquery animation and easing stuff.  Next to nothing imo.

Answer (score 0):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/xeTz5/)

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            $('#upload-title').css({
                background: '#00FF72'
            });
        }, 500
    );
})
```